# How can I change Spinner's item text color?

Tags: android, spinner

```
View view = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
ArrayAdapter<String> adap = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.spin_text), (String[]) getResources().getStringArray(R.array.itemlist));
Spinner spin = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spin);
spin.setAdapter(adap);
```

I'm using spinner like above that.
now, I want change spinner's item color in java code and I tried this like:

```
View view_text = inflater2.inflate(R.layout.spin_text, null);
TextView spin_text = (TextView)view_text.findViewById(R.id.spin_text);

<!-- spin_text.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/spin_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:padding="4dp" >
</TextView>
```

When i click a button, this code works:

```
spin_text.setTextColor(colorCode);
```

but, did not change anything..
what i did wrong?

Comment: Have you tried this? spinner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spinner_background);

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom XML file for your spinner item.

spinner_item.xml:

Give your customized color and size to text in this file.

```
<TextView  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:gravity="left"  
android:textColor="#FF0000"         
android:padding="5dip"
/>
```

Now use this file to show your spinner items like:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_item,list);
```